# Flask HTTPie Connection refused

Tags: python, json, flask, httpie

So I am testing my web service with HTTpie and I am trying to issue a GET request with the following

```
http --json --auth <ADMIN_EMAIL>:<PASSWORD> GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1.0/posts
```

*Removed actual email and password to post here*

```
@api.route('/posts/')
def get_posts():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    pagination = Post.query.paginate(
        page, per_page=current_app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'],
        error_out=False)
    posts = pagination.items
    prev = None
    if pagination.has_prev:
        prev = url_for('api.get_posts', page=page-1, _external=True)
    next = None
    if pagination.has_next:
        next = url_for('api.get_posts', page=page+1, _external=True)
    return jsonify({
        'posts': [post.to_json() for post in posts],
        'prev': prev,
        'next': next,
        'count': pagination.total
    })
```

*api is a blueprint*

And I am getting the following error

```
http: error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

Going to `http://`127.0.0.1/api/v.10/posts` in a browser does work, but it's not clear what's different between the browser and httpie.

Comment: Use `http --verbose`

Comment: Can you post up the rest of you code so that we may have a chance to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @skyline75489 I'm using Flasky by miguel https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky

Comment: @nathancahill using verbose gives the same error e.g http --verbose --json........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so my virtualenv was on python 2.7 and by upgrading it to python 3.4 it seemed to do the trick and have successfully connected!